# Arduino click, double click and hold button

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I am trying to implement three different functions for one button in an Arduino project. Click, double click and hold.
I have to use interrupts and let the system sleep as much as possible, because the final product will have to run on a coin cell for a few months.

```
#include <Ports.h>
#include <RF12.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <PinChangeInt.h>
#include <VirtualWire.h>

ISR(WDT_vect) { Sleepy::watchdogEvent(); }

char *controller;

const int buttonPin = 3;

bool stateSingle = false;
bool stateDouble = false;
bool stateLong = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
//  vw_set_ptt_inverted(true);
//  vw_set_tx_pin(12);
//  vw_setup(4000);
//  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  PCintPort::attachInterrupt(buttonPin, wakeUp, HIGH);
}

void wakeUp() {
}

void loop() {
    cli();

    int i = 0;
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) { // Wait until button is LOW, or has been high for more than 600ms
      Sleepy::loseSomeTime(50);
      if (i > 12)
        break;
      i++;
    }

    if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
      longTapAction();
    else {
      i = 0;
      while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW) { // Wait for possible double press
        Sleepy::loseSomeTime(50);
        if (i > 8)
          break;
        i++;
      }

      if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
          doubleTapAction();

          while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
            Sleepy::loseSomeTime(50);
      } else
        singleTapAction();
    }
}

void singleTapAction() {
  stateSingle = !stateSingle;
  digitalWrite(5, stateSingle ? HIGH : LOW);

  sei();
  Sleepy::powerDown();
}

void doubleTapAction() {
  stateDouble = !stateDouble;
  digitalWrite(6, stateDouble ? HIGH : LOW);

  sei();
  Sleepy::powerDown();
}

void longTapAction() {
  stateLong = !stateLong;
  digitalWrite(7, stateLong ? HIGH : LOW);

  sei();
  Sleepy::powerDown();
}
```

The problem is that this is not always correctly working.
Because I'm using interrupts, `millis()` inside `void loop()` is not reliable, for some reason.

For any double click, and for any hold action, the single click function also gets called. I suspect this is due to multiple interrupts firing, but I have no way to test this. Also, sometimes, the double click seems to need only one click. Is my thinking wrong, did I forget something?

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing `singleTapAction` and `doubleTapAction` triggering too often, the problem could be that your method doesn't really debounce the button inputs, meaning you may read spurious noise on any click as a single press or double press. E.G your first while loop will exit almost immediately if there is a noisy input, which makes the following behavior difficult to predict.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce

If you have a look at the linked example on the arduino site - a possible solution is to record the period of time an input has been present and ignore any inputs of less than a certain period. Modifying your code to do this could stop the spurious calls.

Comment: This makes sense, especially for the extra single click function call, when you put it this way. Wouldn't the example be a bit more complicated when putting the device to sleep, as `millis()` won't increase when sleeping? What would be the best method to still include debouncing?

Comment: When adding something like `static unsigned long last_interrupt_time = 0;
  unsigned long interrupt_time = millis();
  if (interrupt_time - last_interrupt_time > 200) `, the behaviour is still the same.